# Google map doesnt load completely on modal

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps

I'm using google map and jquery 2.1.0 library with open-close modal.

When i put the #map in #main div, it works normally. But when i put the #map in #modal div it doesn't load completely.

Here is html

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="inner">
        <a href="#" id="modal-open">Open</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="modal">
    <div class="inner">
        <a href="#" id="modal-close">Close</a>
                  <div id="map_canvas" style="height:300px; width:600px;"></div>
    <!-- The element that will contain our Google Map. This is used in both the Javascript and CSS above. -->   
    </div>            
</div>
```

My example is here:
http://www.demiray.co/ex/map.html

Answer (score 1):

It is best to initialize Google Maps after you have made the element visible, because the maps API uses information about the element to dictate layout. When the element is not visible, the size information is not reliable and the map you create won't look right when you then make it visible.

Also, although this means there may be a delay when a user requests the map, it means you won't be attempting to load a map for users who don't request one.

So remove this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

And instead call `init()` from within your `$('#modal-open').on('click'` handler - after you have made the element visible. (Yes, this means you may want to re-think your animation as there won't be anything there yet to "fade in".

Comment: Thank you for answer and informations. But how can i call init() function ?